# can access app using url from apple but can't access using app name or keyword in search menu

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store

I first uploaded to the app store, using a new account, and I have a case like this.

I got an email from the app store if our application can be accessed, I tried using the url provided by the appstore, the url worked but I tried the first day after I received the appstore email looking for the application using the search menu the results were not found, the third day the application was able appears using keywords but the fourth day to this day (15 days) the application does not appear using keywords in the search menu is there a solution for this case, I have tried to reply to an email from apple questioning my case but my email has not been replied, thanks for the help.

is one of the ways we use paid search advertising ?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that this problem is on the appstore side, maybe the solution is try emailing apple by clicking contact us => app setup and distribution => app store search and discoveryability => email,

so that the appstore can help display our application in the search menu

[image]